# Panning and zooming to specific coordinate in GMAP3 and JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-gmap3

I'm trying to set use a link on the page to pan and zoom to a specific array of coordinates (where I have a marker already dropped, and gmap3 initialized).  When I click the link, the Javascript fires (I get the alert), but nothing happens in my map.  Please help.  Here is my code:

```
$(".phila").click(function(){
    alert("hello");
    $("#map").gmap3({
        action:'panTo', 
        args:[39.952335, -75.163789]
    });
});
```

Edit: now I am getting an error in the console saying "Uncaught Error: panTo: latLng must be of type LatLng"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you may try this:

```
$('#test1').gmap3(
    {action:'panTo',
     args:[new google.maps.LatLng(-7,110)]}
);
```

it works.

Comment: Could you also include how to use the address feature so you can use "London" instead of numerical coordinates? Thanks

Comment: Works great, Does anyone no why the official doc does not reflect this    or am I missing something. http://gmap3.net/examples/pan-to-markers.html

Answer (score 6):

To zoom using **gmap3** you first need to get a reference to native map object and then simply set the level.

```
var map = $("#map_canvas").gmap3('get');
map.setZoom(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the [expected argument](http://gmap3.net/examples/pan-to-markers.html) is a single point, not two separate arguments, lat, lon.  try:

```
$("#map").gmap3({
   action:'panTo', 
     args:[[39.952335, -75.163789]]
   });
});
```